# Apache Batik and FOP: Can I use two PDFTranscoder instances to generate two PDF files in parallel?

Tags: pdf, svg, parallel-processing, apache-fop, batik

I'm using Batik and PDFTranscoder to generate SVG files and convert them to PDF. I want to generate multiple PDF files in parallel to increase throughput.

The [documentation of Apache FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.3/embedding.html#multithreading) states vaguely: *"Apache FOP may currently not be completely thread safe"* and later: *"In general, you cannot safely run multiple threads through the AWT renderer."* I'm not sharing any objects between threads, but I don't know if the PDFTranscoder uses the *"AWT renderer"* in that sense.

Is it safe to create two instances of PDFTranscoder in two separate threads and use them to generate two PDF files in parallel, or do I have to ensure that at most one PDFTranscoder is being used in a JVM at any time?